# Projectile motion problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

A perfectly elastic ball is thrown against a house and bounces back over the head of the thrower. When it leaves the thrower's hand, the ball is $2\text{m}$ above the ground and $4\text{m}$ from the wall and has $V_{0x} = V_{0y} = 10 \text{ m/s}$. How far behind the thrower does the ball hit the ground.assume g = $10 \text{m/s^2}$.

[image]
I'm stuck in this problem, could anyone give a help? Professor said answer is $2(1 + \sqrt35)$m = $13.8\text{m} $ behind the thrower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem with no house, and then reflect it about the position of the wall.